# Dompdf classe Dompdf

Tags: php

Estou com problemas para gerar pdf com o Dompdf utilizando MVC.
Estou utilizando o seguinte código:

```
// Importa arquivo de config da classe DOMPDF
require_once 'bower_components/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php';


// reference the Dompdf namespace
// use Dompdf\Dompdf;

// instantiate and use the dompdf class
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml('Hello World!');

// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');

// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();

// Get the generated PDF file contents
$pdf = $dompdf->output();

// Output the generated PDF to Browser
$dompdf->stream('testePDF.pdf');
```

O resultado é o seguinte erro: Fatal error:

```
Class 'Dompdf' not found
```

Quando utilizo a seguinte linha:

```
// reference the Dompdf namespace
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
```

O resultado é este:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE)
```

Comment: Esta utilizando algum framework?

Comment: qual a versão do seu PHP

Comment: sem framework, somente MVC e o PHP 5.5.12

Answer (score 0):

Olá, teste desse jeito:

```
// Importa arquivo de config da classe DOMPDF
require_once 'bower_components/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php';
// reference the Dompdf namespace
// use Dompdf\Dompdf;

// instantiate and use the dompdf class
$dompdf = new \Dompdf();
//resto do código
```

Comment: Não deu! continua não achando a classe!

Comment: O mais estranho é que ele funciona perfeitamente em um arquivo separado, mas não funciona dentro da função!

Comment: Tenta ver com o file_exists, se ele está encontrando o arquivo do Dompdf